# Required value in MVC is empty string but modelstate is still valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a required string for my model and I can submit the form and still leave the textbox blank and the model state is being returned as valid so I have no idea what I did wrong. This is the only control on my page that is doing this. Here is my code:

Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Requirements are Required.")]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText, ErrorMessage = "Requirements is Required.")]
[StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "200 Characters is the maximum allowed for requirements.")]
public string Requirements { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Requirements, "Requirements:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Requirements, htmlAttributes: new { @rows = "10", @cols = "50", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Requirements)
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you done a test to see if any of the other attributes could be interfering? (I.e. just have the `[Required]` attribute)

Comment: No not yet. I will try that now

Comment: I cant reproduce this. The validation message is displayed and the form is not submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:
As @Stephen Muecke noted, I cant reproduce your case neither, it should be enough Required attribute.
My answer below somehow Workaround as said by @MajkeloDev.

---

You should put `MinimumLength = 10` for your field. number `200` indicates maximum length for your string

```
[StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "200 Characters is the maximum allowed for requirements.")]
```

**Note**: M`inimumLength = 10` is being some number for a meaningful input. For non empty string it is enough `MinimumLength = 1`

Comment: Did OP said that this string cannot have less than 10 characters?

Comment: @MajkeloDev Because length of `HelloWorld` is 10.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes it is. Please just see note

Comment: No, I mean that OP has made a stupid typo or other error (what is claimed is not possible without some other issue at play) and this answer (which has nothing to do with the question) has been accepted

Comment: Actually if Field is [Required] it means that by default it can't be empty, so there must be some other issue. This is a WorkArrond solution.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak, `[StringLength]` does not override `[Required]`. I have copied OP code into new MVC4 and MVC5 projects and it works as intended (ModelState is not valid). One possible  issue is that OP has rendered `@Html.Hidden(m => m.Requirements)` property before `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Requirements)`. Another is that the property name has been added to the forms route values, but who knows.